# What is the best way to filter list of custom datatype with other list (Iterate over it)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a problem regarding filtering a list with my own type with one other.

I came from python so haskell is quite hard for me to understand.

```
type PersonId = Integer
type PersonName = String
type InfectionId = Integer
type InfectionName = String

data TerminationType = Recovered | Dead
                       deriving (Eq, Show)

data Person = Person PersonId PersonName
              deriving Show

data Infection = Infection InfectionId PersonId InfectionName
                 deriving Show

data Termination = Termination InfectionId TerminationType
                   deriving Show

type Persons = [Person]
type Infections = [Infection]
type Terminations = [Termination]

pers :: Persons
pers = [Person 1 "Augustin"
       ,Person 2 "Baltazar"
       ,Person 42 "Ctirad"
       ,Person 128 "Zdenek"
       ,Person 5 "Drahoslav"
       ]

infs :: Infections
infs = [Infection 2020 1 "COVID"
       ,Infection 2019 42 "COVID"
       ,Infection 1 5 "COVID"
       ,Infection 5 128 "rymicka"
       ,Infection 3 5 "astma"
       ,Infection 2 1 "astma"
       ,Infection 128 5 "zapal plic"
       ]

ters :: Terminations
ters = [Termination 2020 Dead
       ,Termination 2 Recovered
       ,Termination 2019 Recovered
       ,Termination 128 Dead
       ]
```

I am trying to make a function that would find all active cases. So it would make a list of recorded infections based on current infection and remove all terminations.

My idea was to get all IDs from Terminations using a map and then filtering items with that ID from Infections using something like "in" from python but that solution seems to be way too "OOP".

Something along those lines.

```
activeCases :: Infections -> Terminations -> [InfectionId]
activeCases infec term = filter (infec.id in (map getId term)) infec
    where getId (Termination y _) = y
```

The final result with the "pers,infs" and "ters" I have predefined would be

activeCases infs ters ~>*
[Infection 1 5 "COVID",Infection 5 128 "rymicka",Infection 3 5 "astma"]

Could someone tell me what is the right way to solve a problem like this?

Comment: Using a `Map` sounds perfectly appropriate - or actually a `Set`, if you only care about the ids. The operator you're looking for is called [`member`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:member) though, not `in`, and `map` needs to be changed to construct one.

Comment: Oh wait you actually meant to `map` the `getId` function over the list of `term`s to get a list with ids. Yes, that'll work just as well. In that case, use [`elem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem): `filter (\(Infections _ id _) -> id `elem` (map getId term)) infec`

Comment: That is great! Exactly what i need. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> My idea was to get all IDs from Terminations using a map and then filtering items with that ID from Infections using something like "in" from python but that solution seems to be way too "OOP".

Not at all, you have the right idea, in fact! It looks like you just need some help expressing it.

You can change your code to use the `elem` function, which is akin to Python’s `in` operator, but works on any foldable container with equatable elements:

```
elem :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

Here you’ll be using it with `t ~ []` and `a ~ InfectionId`, so it will have the specialised type `elem :: InfectionId -> [InfectionId] -> Bool`.

If you want to return just the IDs, not the whole `Infection` value, you can extract the IDs first with `map`.

```
activeCases :: Infections -> Terminations -> [InfectionId]
activeCases infections terminations

  -- Select the IDs that are *not* found in the list of termination IDs.
  = filter (\ i -> not (i `elem` terminationIds))

    -- Extract the ID from each Infection.
    (map infectionId infections)
  where
    terminationIds = map terminationId term
    terminationId (Termination y _) = y
    infectionId (Infection i _ _) = i
```

Recall that the `filter` condition indicates which elements to *keep*, not which ones to filter *out*, so for the *active* cases you want to add a `not`. My mnemonic for this is “a *coffee filter* lets *coffee* through” (so `filter even` lets `even` values through).

You can simplify this in a few ways, though. First, you can make the `data` types into records and give each field a name so you can extract it (or update it) more conveniently:

```
data Person = Person
  { personId :: PersonId
  , personName :: PersonName
  }
  deriving (Show)

data Infection = Infection
  { infectionId :: InfectionId
  , infectionPerson :: PersonId
  , infectionName :: InfectionName
  }
  deriving (Show)

data Termination = Termination
  { terminationInfection :: InfectionId
  , terminationType :: TerminationType
  }
  deriving (Show)
```

The mapping & filtering can be expressed with a list comprehension, and the `not` and `elem` functions can be combined into `notElem` for convenience. Putting these together:

```
activeCases :: Infections -> Terminations -> [InfectionId]
activeCases infections terminations =
  [ infectionId infection
  | infection <- infections
  , infectionId infection `notElem` terminationIds
  ]
  where
    terminationIds =
      [ terminationInfection termination
      | termination <- terminations
      ]
```

You can still use pattern-matching in the comprehension if you prefer:

```
-- Positional matching:

[ i
| Infection i _ _ <- infections
, i `notElem` terminationIds
]

-- Named matching:

[ i
, Infection { infectionId = i } <- infections
, i `notElem` terminationIds
]
```

There are higher-level approaches as well. Scanning linearly over the list of `Termination` IDs for each `Infection` ID is O(n<sup>2</sup>), but what you really want here is a *set difference*, which can be computed more efficiently using map & set data structures such as `Data.Map` and `Data.Set` (or `Data.IntMap` and `Data.IntSet`) from `containers`. For example, if you store your data as a map from the ID to the record for that ID:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Set (Set)

type Persons = Map PersonId Person
type Infections = Map InfectionId Infection
type Terminations = Map InfectionId Termination

infs :: Infections
infs = Map.fromList
  [ (i, infection)
  | infection <-
    [ Infection 2020 1 "COVID"
    , Infection 2019 42 "COVID"
    , Infection 1 5 "COVID"
    , Infection 5 128 "rymicka"
    , Infection 3 5 "astma"
    , Infection 2 1 "astma"
    , Infection 128 5 "zapal plic"
    ]
  , let i = infectionId infection
  ]
```

Then the set of active cases is the key-set of the infections minus the set of terminated cases, which can be computed in O(*n* log *n*) time:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

activeCases :: Infections -> Terminations -> Set InfectionId
activeCases infections terminations
  = infectionIds `Set.difference` terminatedInfections
  where
    infectionIds = Map.keysSet infections
    terminatedInfections = Set.fromList
      $ map terminationInfection
      $ Map.elems terminations
```

Or since a `Termination` is identified by an `InfectionId` as well, just the difference of the key sets:

```
Map.keysSet infections `Set.difference` Map.keysSet terminations
```

Comment: God bless your children. You, dear lord, just opened my third eye and allowed me to see everything the right way.